# Conditional expectation and variance of a poisson distribution, where $_$ is conditioned on $_{−1}$

Tags: variance, expected-value, poisson-distribution, conditional

Suppose that $_0 \sim \text{Poi}()$ (where $ > 0$ is fixed) and that for $ = 1, 2,…$ the distribution
of $_$ conditional on $_{−1} = $ is Poisson with parameter $$.

Determine formulas for $[_]$ and $\text{Var}(_)$ (for all $ = 0, 1, 2, …$ ).

Comment: Been struggling with this for a while, would really appreciate it if someone could help

Comment: can you include your attempt in your post, describing where you are stuck and use the self-study tag?